# Why are birds attracted to airports?

Tags: bird-strike, birds

Birds are usually around airside. Apart from answering it myself, I am looking for community knowledge on this topic.

Comment: They probably enjoy watching the planes

Comment: Same principle as hunters using giant decoy geese

Comment: ARE birds actually attracted to airports?  Compared to say other open grassy spaces like parks...

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! If you don't get a good answer here you might try asking on [biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/). As jamesqf pointed out, it isn't clear if birds are *more* attracted to airports than to any other similar environment. The reasons why birds prefer one place to another seem more like biology than aviation to me.

Answer (score 2):

Airports are a wide, open space with a full environment. The attractiveness of vegetation is a balance between food presence, food accessibility, and protection against predators.

[image: Airfield shows short grass to avoid the presence of birds.]

And these factors vary a lot for every bird or animal species.

Food
Food accessibility depends on vegetation height and density. Long, dense vegetation will inhibit most hazardous birds/wildlife from moving around, detecting and accessing the food. In addition, birds/wildlife feeding on seeds will avoid the airport if its vegetation is mowed during the flowering season.

Depredators
On the other hand, many species prefer to stay in the open space of short vegetation where they have a wide view to see predators well in advance to enable them to flee on time; and safeguard themselves from predators by hiding or fleeing.

(from [AirportBirdControl Blog: 6 most asked questions and answers](https://airportbirdcontrol.com/airport-bird-control-6-most-asked-questions-and-answers/))

Comment: Just to be clear, I am the author of the post.

Comment: Please make sure to cite the sources for your images by editing them into your answer.